# Press 'continue' button in simpletest

Tags: testing

I am trying to enable modules via POSTing to /admin/modules in a simpletest. It works fine, except that there are dependencies (the whole reason I want to do it this way) and when it requires then "Continue" button be pressed on the module enable confirmation page, it fails, claiming it couldn't find the button. Here's the code:

```
    $this->drupalPost('admin/modules', $edit, t('Save configuration'));
    $this->assertResponse('200');
    $this->drupalPost('admin/modules/list/confirm', $edit, t('Continue'));
    $this->assertResponse('200');
```

Not only does it fail, it also seems to skip over the first `assertResponse()`.

How do I enable modules with lots of dependencies in simpletests?